# Computing mean of all tuple values where 1st number is similar

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, mean

Consider list of tuples

```
[(7751, 0.9407466053962708), (6631, 0.03942129), (7751, 0.1235432)]
```

how to compute mean of all tuple values in pythonic way where 1st number is similar? for example the answer has to be

```
[(7751, 0.532144902698135), (6631, 0.03942129)]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is using `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
lst = [(7751, 0.9407466053962708), (6631, 0.03942129), (7751, 0.1235432)]
d_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in lst:
    d_dict[k].append(v)

[(k,sum(v)/len(v)) for k,v in d_dict.items()]
#[(7751, 0.5321449026981354), (6631, 0.03942129)]
```

Answer (score 5):

You do with `groupby` ,

```
from itertools import groupby
result = []
for i,g in groupby(sorted(lst),key=lambda x:x[0]):
    grp = list(g)
    result.append((i,sum(i[1] for i in grp)/len(grp)))
```

Using, `list comprehension`,

```
def get_avg(g):
    grp = list(g)
    return sum(i[1] for i in grp)/len(grp)

result = [(i,get_avg(g)) for i,g in groupby(sorted(lst),key=lambda x:x[0])]
```

Result

```
[(6631, 0.03942129), (7751, 0.5321449026981354)]
```

Comment: Also, where is the `mean` ?

Comment: @danihp Updated answer. Thanks.

Comment: List comprehension would be more beautiful.

Comment: @Elmex80s `g` is generator, So it's difficult to get the length. So it's almost impossible.

Comment: @Elmex80s Updated with list comprehension,

Answer (score 3):

`groupby` from `itertools` is your friend:

```
>>> l=[(7751, 0.9407466053962708), (6631, 0.03942129), (7751, 0.1235432)] 

>>> #importing libs:
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from statistics import mean              #(only python >= 3.4)
>>> # mean=lambda l: sum(l) / float(len(l))  #(for python < 3.4) (*1)

>>> #set the key to group and sort and sorting
>>> k=lambda x: x[0]         
>>> data = sorted(l, key=k)  

>>> #here it is, pythonic way:
>>> [ (k, mean([m[1] for m in g ])) for k, g in groupby(data, k) ]
```

Results:

```
[(6631, 0.03942129), (7751, 0.5321449026981354)]
```

**EDITED** (*1) Thanks [Elmex80s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5707684/elmex80s) to refer me to [mean](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html).

Comment: numpy has a mean. You could do `float(np.mean(zip(*g)[1]))`.

Comment: @Elmex80s, yea, is right you say! You know if It worths to import the whole numpy just to make a mean?

Comment: There is also this light weight statistics module https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html which has a mean, Python 3 only it seems.