# Get Average by group in python

Tags: python

Input is like this:

```
G1: 12
G2: 15
G1: 9
G3: 18
G2: 17
G3: 6
G1: 20
```

Output should be average of individual groups like G1: 12+9+20/3 = 13.67,
G2: 15+17/2 = 16, G3: 6+18/2 = 12

Comment: Is all people making the same exercise? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007236/computing-mean-of-all-tuple-values-where-1st-number-is-similar

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: I guess you should to explain how do you store your 'input'.

Comment: show us some code, what did you try?

Comment: We are not here to solve you your homework/exercise, please write what have you tried and failed and what code you have currently. Also, elaborate on the way you save your input (Or, how you iterate it)

Comment: got this question in an interview.not sure how to save 'input' ,may be in tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `list` of dictionaries for the groups:

```
groups = [{'G1': 12},
          {'G2': 15},
          {'G1': 9},
          {'G3': 18},
          {'G2': 17},
          {'G3': 6},
          {'G1': 20}]
```

Getting values into their groups:

```
result = dict()

for d in groups:
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k in result:
            result[k].append(v)
        else:
            result[k] = [v]
```

Calculating averages group-wise:

```
averages = []

for d in result:
    averages.append((d, sum(result[d]) / len(result[d])))

print(averages)

[('G1', 13.666666666666666), ('G2', 16.0), ('G3', 12.0)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the input to a .txt file and then you can try something like this :

> First method : with `collections.defaultdict`

```
import collections
track=collections.defaultdict(list)
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        key,value=line.split(':')
        track[key].append(int(value))


print(list(map(lambda x:(x,sum(track[x])/len(track[x])),track.keys())))
```

output:

```
[('G3', 12.0), ('G1', 13.666666666666666), ('G2', 16.0)]
```

> Second method : pure logic without any external module

```
track={}
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        key,value=line.split(':')
        if key not in track:
            track[key]=[int(value)]
        else:
            track[key].append(int(value))

print(list(map(lambda x:(x,sum(track[x])/len(track[x])),track.keys())))
```

output:

```
[('G1', 13.666666666666666), ('G2', 16.0), ('G3', 12.0)]
```